About CSSStyleDeclaration objects
I've been exploring the behavior of the style property on DOM elements, specifically element.style, which is an instance of CSSStyleDeclaration. I understand that element.style allows access to inline styles and dynamically reflects changes to the element's style attribute. However, I'm puzzled about the following behavior:
When I inspect element.style with Object.getOwnPropertyNames, I see a large number of own properties corresponding to all possible CSS properties:
const div = document.createElement('div');
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(div.style));

This outputs an array with numerous property names such as color, backgroundColor, etc.
I have a few questions about this behavior:

Does this mean that div.style stores its state directly on the object unlike e.g. div.nodeType (a getter residing in Node.prototype) which routes itself to the native browser environment in order to fetch the value from the native DOM?
If the properties are defined on the object, how does CSSStyleDeclaration manage changes to the inline style attribute in sync with these properties?

I'm trying to better understand how CSSStyleDeclaration works under the hood and am seeking for a reliable answer and/or references.

Mostly answered here

"works under the hood" start looking at browser source code for those that have open source.
